# Binary Matrix Multiplication in Java

Tags: java, math, matrix, jar

I want to do binary matrix multiplication in Java. Is there any class or jar available for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I needed was found in [Binary Matrix](http://en.literateprograms.org/Binary_matrix_%28Java%29).

Suggested to me by `uba`

Answer (score 0):

The following java package may be helpful http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

Comment: Sorry, i am not able to find anything regarding binary matrix multiplication in the provided link.

Comment: Then this could be your requirement: http://en.literateprograms.org/Binary_matrix_%28Java%29